An error problem about using eclipse CDT to debug C language in Ubuntu system: Can't find a source file at "./stdio-common/./stdio-common/printf.c"
The following problem occurs when using eclipse CDT to debug C language in Ubuntu system:
Whenever debugging enters the print line, an error program appears, causing debugging to be interrupted. As shown in the following code：
Can't find a source file at "./stdio-common/./stdio-common/printf.c"
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int arr[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int* parr = &arr[0];
    int i = 0;
    int sz = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    for(i = 0; i< sz;i++){
    *   printf("%d ",*(parr+i));*
    }
    return 0;
}

enter image description here
enter image description here
If you can give the right guidance, I will be very grateful.
A Correct C Language Debugger

It is not an error, and not a problem. The debugger is telling you that iit cannot find the source code of printf. Unless you implemented printf yourself, or built it from sources, you shouldn't have its source code. So it's completely normal. Just continue debugging.

Haven't used Eclipse in a long time, but the usual solution is to use "step over" for that line, instead ot "step into". You are not debugging printf, right?
